# How to concatenate a link and an input for an iframe source using JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have here a script that let users enter a URL in an input, and it will show it in the same page via iframe.

However, the users use this tool for a specific type of predictable link.

It has a pattern of something like this: `https://sample.app/111-222.pdf`

What I'd like to achieve is to have a hidden `https://sample.app/` and then concatenate it with the user entered value like `111-222` and concatenate it again with a hidden `.pdf`

I'd like for it not be visible in the input, it's like when a user enterd 111-222, the iframe will immediately show the page, but the link should stay out of sight.

Please see my code here:

```js
$('input#acturl').on('propertychange paste keyup',function(){
  var url = this.value;
  $('#actframe').attr('src', url);
});
$('input#acturl').keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="card-body text-center">

<input class="form-control form-control-sm inputcopybtn noenter" type="text" id="acturl" value="" placeholder="Paste a URL"/>

<iframe id="actframe" src="" loading="lazy" width="100%" height="735" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>

</div>
```

I just couldn't figure out how to pull this off. But what I have in mind is by doing something like this, but without a button:

`<a onClick="javascript: window.open('https://sample.app/' + document.getElementById('acturl').value + '.pdf');">Go</a>`

Would really like to move on from this. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simple solution, by adding 2 more input bars. However, the problem now is how to trigger an enter button or keypress on the hidden input for result so that it will be activated?

```js
$('#actpart1, #actpart2, #section10a').bind('keypress blur', function() {
    $('#acturl').val('https://sample.app/' + $('#actpart1').val() + '/' +
                            $('#actpart2').val() + '.pdf');
});

$('input#acturl').on('propertychange paste keyup',function(){
  var url = this.value;
  $('#actframe').attr('src', url);
});
$('input#acturl').keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="card-body text-center">

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="actpart1" value="116-2"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="actpart2" value="116-261"/>
    
<input accesskey="q" class="form-control form-control-sm inputcopybtn noenter" type="text" id="acturl" value="" hidden/>

<iframe id="actframe" src="" loading="lazy" width="100%" height="735" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>

</div>
```

So far it's working if the final input is not hidden and I can press enter to activate it. This is the last step for this and I'm done with this.